# LINQ list exclude item with latest datetime

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects, the object contains a datetime.

I want to use LINQ to exclude the object with the latest datetime.

I'm trying something like:

```
var excludedList = testdata.Except(testdata.Max(c => c.registeredAt).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

But it does not work, what should the correct linq be?

Comment: What if there are multiple with the same latest datetime?

Comment: That is not possible

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
var excludedList = testdata.OrderByDescending(i => i.registeredAt).Skip(1).ToList();
```

This will sort the list by date, then skip the first item.

Comment: That will modify the order which was not requested

Comment: What if there're *two* records with the same (*maximum*) `registeredAt`? You have to call `.Skip(2)` in this case?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: The OP said that is not possible

Comment: @TimSchmelter: True, but in many cases it would be acceptable to change the order. Really depends what the OP is doing with the list. :)

Comment: @Baldrick: since a `List<T>` is one of the ordered collections in the framework i would not presume that it doesn't matter. The problem is that you can't modify your solution easily to restore the original order, can you?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Point taken. My reasoning is that this approach produces simpler code which might well hold in the OP's case. Let's see what the OP's response is I guess!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't perform a whole sort just to extract a single maximum value, and preserves the order of the sequence. It does still depend on the maximum value being unique.

```
var maxRegisteredAt = testdata.Max(c => c.registeredAt);
var excludedList = testdata
    .Where(c => c.registeredAt != maxRegisteredAt)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible approach if duplicate `registeredAt` datetimes aren't possible:

```
var maxObj = testdata.OrderByDescending(x => x?.registeredAt).First();
var excludedList = testdata.FindAll(x => x != maxObj);
```

This keeps the original order.